# Реализация перемотки видео в самописном плеере

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, видео

Сейчас я из интереса пишу свой видео плеер на `Pyhton3` и `opencv`.

Уже написал реализовал воспроизведение звука и видео, но не понимаю как нормально реализовать перемотку видео, потому что нашел только команду получения следующего кадра видео:

```py
cap.read()
```

Можно ли как-то получить конкретный кадр?

Comment: https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781788474443/1/ch01lvl1sec24/jumping-between-frames-in-video-files

Comment: opencv вроде бы не очень предназначен для подобных дел